# How to centralize Django base.html from remote location

Tags: python-3.x, django

I need to set up a project which is across multiple departments. The VP wants to centralize all the CSS. JS and base.html. Those files need to control by QA and no one should have access to them. Does Django have some function like PHP  tag, I can force Base.html include header, navi bar, side bar and footer. please help, thanks

Comment: `Does Django have some function like PHP tag`: Which PHP tag? What is wrong with simply extending `base.html`?

Comment: on PHP something like <?php include 'footer.html';?>, therefore, we can centralize control the header.html, and other sections.